# MutableProperty containing a dictionary in ReactiveSwift

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

I am using ReactiveSwift to create a struct containing a dictionary. I want to listen for changes in the dictionary.

```
struct Model {
    let a: MutableProperty<[String: Int]> = MutableProperty([:])
}
```

However, I'm having a hard time understanding how to bind this property to a listener. I want to do something like:

```
textView.reactive.text <~ model.a["key"]
```

Is there a solution to holding dictionaries in mutable properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the MutableProperty associated value (in your case, the dictionary) is able to be binded to the binding target, and not a value within the dictionary. That means you can't use the `<~` operator on a value from the dictionary. You'll need to do something like:

```
model.a.producer.startWithValues { [weak textView] value in
     textView?.text = value["key"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very useful! I ended up making the properties inside my dictionary mutable, but that assumes the dictionary is a fixed size. Your answer works for the unknown case.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do it like this:

```
textView.reactive.text <~ model.a.map { $0["key"] }
```